# Show that the function $f(x) = x^{2}|\cos(\pi /x)|$ is not differentiable at $x = 2n/(2n+1)$ but is at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I found this problem while trying out different things, and I'm curious to see how this works. i've been having a lot of trouble and my teacher is out of town this week. I need to show that

$$f(x) = x^{2}|\cos(\pi /x)|$$

isn't  differentiable at $x=2n/(2n+1)$ but is differentiable at $0$. I'm not sure exactly how to get the derivative. Using Wolfram Alpha I got 
$$(4 x |\cos(\pi/x)|^2+\pi \sin((2 \pi)/x))/(2 |\cos(\pi/x)|)$$

but I'm unsure. Plugging in $x=2n/(2n+1)$ didn't yield anything.

Comment: The title states a different thing that the body of your question. Can you clear a bit this? 

It must be something like

"$f(x)=x^2\left|\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)\right|$ is not differentiable at $x=\frac{2}{2n+1}$ but is at $0$."

Comment: Notice that your function is not defined at $x=0$, then it cannot be differentiable in that point. I suspect that the function has the form
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2|\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)|&\text{if }x\neq 0\\ 0&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be defined by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2|\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)|&\text{if }x\neq 0\\ 0&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$$
First, we are going to prove that $f$ is differentiable at $0$, since $f(0)=0$ we have
\begin{align}
0&\leq\left|\frac{h^2|\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{h}\right)|-0}{h}\right|\le |h|\\
0&\leq \left|\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\right|\le |h|
\end{align}
Then, by the Sandwich Theorem, if follows that the limit $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$$
exists and also it is equal to $0$. So $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that if $f(a)= 0$ and $f'(a) \ne 0,$ then $|f|$ is not differentiable at $a.$ (A look at the picture shows why.)